# C++ VSCode Intellisense Popup is Lacking Proper Description/Linting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I installed Microsoft's C++ extension on VSCode, but when I'm writing C++ code,
[my screen looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyPtT.png)

The autocompletion feature works, but there is no documentation/proper description given to me for any of the built-in C++ functions/classes. Compare the above to what it looks like on [an official screenshot of the C++ VSCode extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2ERP.png).

I have my \msys64\mingw64\bin folder added to path too, so there shouldn't be a problem there. Any suggestions on how I can fix the tooltips my IDE gives me for C++?